# Use powershell to get instance description and tags

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-powershell

Is there a way of getting instance's description (eg, instance ID, AMI ID, VPC ID....etc) and tags using Powershell?

I tried  `Get-EC2Instance | select *` but it doesn't give all the information I need.

Answer (score 3):

Good starting point would be to store your instances in a variable.

```
$ec2 = Get-EC2Instance
$ec2.instances
```

will display all the info you can get.

Same can be done like this

```
(Get-EC2Instance).Instances
```

or filter only what you need.

```
(Get-EC2Instance).Instances | select-object ImageId,InstanceId,VpcId
```